# Kivy recycleview not scrolling smoothly

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

I'm developing a music player mobile application using **kivy2.0.0**, in the app there is a playlist screen that consist of more than 100 **mdboxlayout** widget called '**MusicListItem**'.

I have these 2 problems with the app:

1. The scrolling part is not scrolling smoothly and sometimes select things when scrolling on android devices
2. I want when I select a particular Item, a function to be called and change the icon of the MDIconButton of that selected item to 'pause'.

**This is my .py file**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RectangularRippleBehavior
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_file('playlist.kv')

KV = """
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()

    Playlist:
        name: "playlist screen"

"""

class Playlist(ThemableBehavior, MDScreen):
    rv = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

    def music_list(self):
        return ['audio '+str(i) for i in range(1, 121)]

    def _finish_init(self, dt):
        self.set_list_musics()
        self.ids.rv.data[0]["icon"] = 'pause'

    def set_list_musics(self):
        """Builds a list of audios for the screen Playlist."""
        print(self.ids)

        def add_music_item(num, sura, secText, icon):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "MusicListItem",
                    "number": num,
                    "text": sura,
                    "secondary_text": secText,
                    "icon": icon,
                    "callback": lambda x:x})
    
        for i in range(len(self.music_list())):
            music = self.music_list()
            add_music_item(str(i+1), music[i], '00:00:00', 'play')
         
    
class MusicListItem(ThemableBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    secondary_text = StringProperty()
    number = StringProperty()
    icon = StringProperty()
    
    
class Mp3Player(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
       
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


if '__main__' == __name__:
    Mp3Player().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
#: import gch kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<Playlist>
    md_bg_color: gch("#5D1049")
        
    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1
        
        MDToolbar:
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: x]]
            right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: x]]
            elevation: 10
            md_bg_color: 75/255, 6/255, 54/255, 1
            title: 'Playlist'
            pos_hint: {'top':1}
                    
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
           
            RecycleView:
                id: rv
                viewclass: 'MusicListItem'

                RecycleBoxLayout:
                    padding: dp(10)
                    default_size: None, dp(60)
                    default_size_hint: 1, None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    orientation: 'vertical'

     
<MusicListItem>
    size_hint_y: None
    padding: dp(14)
    height: dp(60)

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:
                self.theme_cls.divider_color
        Line:
            points: (root.x+dp(10), root.y, root.x+self.width-dp(10)-0, root.y)

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_x: .2
              
                MDLabel:
                    text: root.number
                    font_style: "H6"
                    adaptive_height: True
                
                MDLabel:
                    size_hint_y: .3
                 
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
             
                MDLabel:
                    text: root.text
                    font_style: "Subtitle2"
                    adaptive_height: True
    
                MDLabel:
                    text: root.secondary_text
                    font_style: "Caption"
                    theme_text_color: "Hint"
                    adaptive_height: True

            MDIconButton:
                icon: root.icon
```

please any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I found no scrolling issue.

Secondly, in order to select a specific item in `RecycleView` you need some button-like behavior in that specific item (viewclass) which will trigger some action when interacted with.

Thus your modified `MusicListItem` should now look like,

```py
class MusicListItem(ThemableBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, ButtonBehavior, MDBoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()
    secondary_text = StringProperty()
    number = StringProperty()
    icon = StringProperty()

    def on_release(self, *args):
        self.icon = "pause"
        print(f"Selected item no. {self.number}")
```

Just remember to trigger any action at instance level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the second probem is solved but for the first problem, the scrolling work fine on computers but misbehave on some android device, please how to make scroll of recycleview more smoothly

Comment: Try changing `effect_cls` property of `RecycleView` with different options.

Comment: Also try changing `scroll_x`, `scroll_y` values.

Comment: Changing effect_cls to 'ScrollEffect' reduce the lag, but I dont understand what you mean by changing scroll_x, scroll_y values, please if you can make an example I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Also how can I make the icon of MDIconButton of only selected item change to 'pause' and all others to be 'play'. Thanks once again

Comment: Please have a look at [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html). For your second query about '*how can I make the icon of MDIconButton...*' you should consider posting a new question.

Comment: I post the new question, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728159/how-to-select-only-one-button-in-kivy-recycleview